# Querying available rental dates for a vehicle

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble how to implement a search functionality on a website I'm working on.

The search form has two fields, starting date and an end date which a user wants to rent a vehicle.

In the database I have two tables, one for the vehicle and another one for available dates.

```
Table: cars
 - car_id (int)
 - name (varchar)
 - description (varchar)

Table: cars_availability
 - car_id (int)
 - date (datetime)
 - status (int) // 1: available 2: booked
```

Each row in **cars_availability** represent a day that the associated car is available for rent or booked.

**Problem:**

If user searches for a car that is available from **5.feb.2013** to **8.feb.2013** I would like to do a query to select all cars that are available for all the days in the users selection.

**My current unfinished solution:**

I know I can iterate through all the days using something like this

```
$begin = new \DateTime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['rent_start'])));
$end = new \DateTime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['rent_end'])));
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$available_cars = array();

foreach ( $period as $dayTime ){

    // query the cars and joining the cars_availabilty table

    $item = DB::select('cars.*')
    ->from('cars')
    ->join('cars_availability')->on('cars_availability.item_id', '=', 'cars.item_id')
    ->where('items_availability.date', '=', $dayTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
    ->and_where('items_availability.status', '=', 1)
    ->execute()->as_array();

    if(count($item) > 0){

      if(isset($available_cars[$item[0]['item_id']])){

        $available_cars[$item[0]['item_id']][] = $item[0];

      }else{

        $available_cars[$item[0]['item_id']] = array();
        $available_cars[$item[0]['item_id']][] = $item[0];
      }
    }

}
```

After this I would have an array of vehicles that might have all the days available but I would need to do some extra math to find that out.

I want know if there is some more elegant solutions to this problem, using a better query maybe.

If you can give me any feedback on this I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: LOGIC : select all the cars with status 'available' or all the cars with status 'booked' where available from 5.feb.2013 is not between rent_start and rent_end

Comment: Off topic: Instead of keeping the records with status I would instead create a `booked` table with `car_id`,`from_date` and `to_date` so that I could know if a car will be available by checking the records in this table against a given date period. I would additionally create a column `client_id` (FK to some `clients` table) there. My 2 cents.

Comment: @inhan - agreed, a much better design for space savings.  A 'calendar' table can be used to show all 'available' dates if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a fairly sane setup to query.  Personally, I'd recommend following @inhan's advice, especially if it turns out cars can be booked for smaller slices of time (hours?).  However, the queries get a little bit more complicated to write, because of edge-cases (if you look around here, you should find relevant examples).

Unfortunately, I can't speak to how this fits into your framework, but the SQL can look like this:

```
SELECT Cars.car_id, Cars.name, Cars.description
FROM Cars
JOIN (SELECT car_id
      FROM Cars_Availability
      WHERE `date` >= '2013-02-05'
            AND `date` < '2013-02-09'
            AND status = 1
      GROUP BY car_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF('2013-02-09', '2013-02-05')) Available
  ON Available.car_id = Cars.car_id
```

(Have an [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f970/2))
This query assumes that there's only one entry per day, or this breaks.  Basically, it grabs every 'available' row greater-than/equal the beginning date, and less than the 'end' date (date/time/timestamps are... complicated; [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) deals with SQL Server-specific problems, but the basic concepts apply), and makes sure there's one for the count of days between them.  Mostly, you were looking for the `HAVING` clause.
Given the proper index on `Cars_Availability`, it may not even hit the table, making this a good performer, too.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, this seems to be exactly the thing I'm looking for. Cars will never be bookable for less then a day so this won't break.